# When to read 一人 and 二人 as いちにん and ににん?

Tags: numbers, readings, counters

WWWJDIC lists いちにん and ににん as alternative readings of 一人 {ひとり} and 二人 {ふたり}, but I can't recall anywhere I heard those readings except when counting more than 10 people for example 三十一人 {さんじゅういちにん}. Is that the only situation where 一人 and 二人 are read as いちにん and ににん, or are there any other situations?

Comment: I think I read in some manga where いちにん　ににん occurs when you're saying something like "one or two people", as in 一　二人 (いち　ににん).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other than your example `三十一人`, I can think of `一人前`, `二人前`, `二人三脚`, `二人羽織`. But by itself, I don't think they are read as 'いちにん' or 'ににん'.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of is `一人称【いちにんしょう】` and `二人称【ににんしょう】` meaning "first person" and "second person" respectively.  This means "person" as in "point-of-view" or parts of speech ("third person" is `三人称【さんにんしょう】`).

Comment: I think that, in those cases, it is not `一人` + `称` but is `一` + `人称`.

Comment: `一人前【いちにんまえ】`、`二人前【ににんまえ】`? Right, probably `一`+`人前`

Comment: @syocit There is no such word as `人前`.

Comment: @sawa Actually 人前 is there in WWWJDIC. Moreover it has two readings with different meanings: にんまえ = food portion, ひとまえ = the public, company ..

Comment: @Lukman I see. But I don't think WWWJDIC is right. And you're right, it can be read as 'ひとまえ', which is a different word.