# Non-universal counters and reading 7 and 9

Tags: readings, numbers

Q1. Why are these counters like 人(にん), 日(にち) and 歳(さい) not universal?

1. 人(にん) is impossible to be joined with 1(いち) or 2(に)?
2. 日(にち) is impossible to be joined with 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 20 or 24?
3. 歳(さい) is impossible to be joined with 20(にじゅう)?

Q2. When do we read 7 and 9 as "しち" and "く" rather than "なな" and "きゅう"?

Comment: Related (regarding しち, なな etc): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/328/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77772/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20881/9831, (regarding ふたり, ににん etc.): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2833/9831 /

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113736/discussion-on-question-by-niconii-non-universal-counters-and-reading-7-and-9).

Comment: There are too many individual questions being asked here.  There needs to be a specific focus.